# How to modify value in a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

So i have a pandas series with some values that i pass over a few times in a loop. 
and each time i want to append something new to the series at that index.

e.g. 
I have a big dataframe called df. Then i create a new column and try to modify it if a condition is satisfied in an interation of a list called someList

```
df["mySeries"] = ""
for a,b in itertools.combinations(someList, 2):
  if int1>0.5:
    df["mySeries"][someList.index(a)] = df["mySeries"][someList.index(a)], b
```

essentially i want to concatenate another string to an existing series. I cant seem to find the best way to do this. The way i wrote works ok, but also gives me a pandas warning:

```
         "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame"
```

and the output isnt clean as it looks something like this: (('', 61), 94) 
and i want it to look more like 61, 94. 
I have tried set_value, but that overwrites existing data inside the series.

Comment: Could you please provide some more code? What are `SomeList` and `int1`? You might find useful to read about [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Then you can't create a new columns on a `pd.Series`. You better run `df.to_frame()`.

Answer (score 0):

As the traceback suggests, you need to use `.loc`.

```
>>> df.loc[someList.index(a), "mySeries"] = ...
```